# Portable database for C#

Tags: c#, database, portability

I know that this may seem as a question that was already asked, but I tried the solutions out there already.

I am building a program with C# and I need to save data in a way that every client has his own fresh (dynamic path) to his db. What can I do so users won't need to install extra things, but just .NET framework?

I heard about SQLite, but I didn't really get it working.

Comment: What platforms do you plan to support? Just Windows? Also if you data model is simple, consider a file based store instead of a DB. Otherwise SQL Server is probably the best bet.

Comment: SQLite supports multiple platforms

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by portable?  If you mean X-Plat then SQL compact is not the answer (although very capable on windows).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sql Server CE. It runs in-process and you can deploy all required assemblies with your application. See this article:

[How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact 3.5 Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Update: Adding some other SQL Server CE related links that I have found helpful:

- [SQL Server Compact “Private Deployment” on desktop–an overview](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/sql-server-compact-private-deployment.html)
- [Using SQL Server Compact 4.0 with Desktop Private Deployment and a Setup project (MSI) (part 2)](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html)
- [Privately Deploying SQL Server Compact with the ADO.NET Entity Provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/22/privately-deploying-sql-server-compact-with-the-ado-net-entity-provider.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Download the SQLite .NET data provider [here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) and then reference System.Data.SQLite.dll from within your application. The following example should work right off the bat.

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=yourfile.db;Version=3;"))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
  connection.Open();
  command.CommandText = "select name from from sqlite_master";
  using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Convert.String(reader["name"]));
    }
  }
}
```

Of course all it does is list the tables in the specified file. If the file does not exist then it will be created automatically and naturally there will not be any tables in it. But, at the very least it *should* work.

Comment: The link not working now, How can i download it :(

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/
get it via nuget like: `Install-Package System.Data.SQLite -Version 1.0.114.4`

Answer (score 3):

You could try SQL Server Compact Edition -

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The official SQLite QuickStart:

http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Code samples for System.Data.Sqlite, on the original support forums:

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/76.aspx

You can find a few alternatives to SQLite in the answers to this related SO question:

[Alternatives to SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417917/alternatives-to-sqlite)

Comment: Second link not working

Comment: Third link also not working

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, c#.net can interface with a sql database without separate server software.  You would just import system.data.sqlclient.

SQL could work for you, but the reason that there is no simple way to get started with it is that database architecture is not a simple subject.  There are plenty of great books out there to get you started if you choose to go that route.  It deals specifically with the syntax of MSSQL, but "T-SQL Fundamentals" by Itzik Ben-Gan is a helpful one.  Of course, syntax variations between different iterations of sql are extremely common, and not a huge burden once you know the idiosyncrasies of the one you happen to be dealing with.

Comment: Not exactly. There's SQL Server Compact Edition, which @ipr101 mentioned. Full SQL Server requires an installed service.